# Check if string is of alias type

Tags: go

This question is more about finding a way to avoid boilerplate code. So I have this example Golang code:

```
type AccountType string

const (
    AccountTypeAdmin AccountType = "admin"
    AccountTypeUser  AccountType = "user"
)
```

And now let's say I expose my API that accepts a `string` parameter that I want to check if it's of type `AccountType`. I can achieve this by making a switch case and checking if this `string` matches any of the `AccountType` `const`s I've created.

Now, as I couldn't find any good answer online, my question is:
What if I will have 10, 20, or even more `const`s? Is there any better/faster way to validate if the `string` is of alias type `AccountType`? Or to be more precise - is the `string` any from the enumerated types?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/HRI55_mYzHq

Comment: Your code contains no aliases so the question makes little sense. But you might want to take a look at the stringer tools.

Comment: Go doesn't have exhaustive enums, so there's not a way to do this without also registering your constants in an iterable. If you don't want to do that, this might fit your needs: https://github.com/orsinium-labs/enum

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch statement for a type.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type AccountType string

const (
    AccountTypeAdmin AccountType = "admin"
    AccountTypeUser  AccountType = "user"
)

func do(param interface{}) {
    switch v := param.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("Parameter is a string - %s\n", v)
    case AccountType:
        fmt.Printf("Parameter is an AccountType - %s\n", v)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("I don't know about type %T! - %v\n", v, v)
    }
}

func main() {
    do(AccountTypeUser)
    do("stringValue")
    do(true)
}
```

Read more about type switches - https://golangdocs.com/type-switches-in-golang

Comment: What I mean is if you take the `func do(param string)`, how can you check if the `param` is any of the constants? Specifically when there are 20+ of these consts? Looking for a quicker solution to no iterate through all cases in the switch statement

Comment: I think there is no way to check if your select block covers all consts. You should use different data structure (map or slice).

Answer (score -1):

My English is not very good。
I think there are several ways：
1.slice contains
2.map hit
3.return str == a || str == b || str == c
4.reflect
Either use extra space or sacrifice some efficiency

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).